# Use rvinecop to generate from a copula with original units

Tags: r

I have a fairly high dimensional dataset that is not mvnormal. I can fit a copula to it using `rvinecopulib`. What I'm unsure about is how to use `rvinecop` on the model to do random generation. I have an example below from the palmer penguin data. How can I fit the copula and then pull n random samples from that modeled hypersphere? To fit the model the data are converted to normalized ranked data with `pseudo_obs` . How do I convert them back. Use the marginal distributions?

```
# copula pens
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(rvinecopulib)


data("penguins")

dat <- penguins %>% na.omit() %>% filter(species=="Adelie") %>%
  select(body_mass_g,bill_depth_mm,flipper_length_mm)

u <- pseudo_obs(dat) # change to rank

# fit and select the model structure, family and parameters
fit <- vinecop(u)
fit
summary(fit)
contour(fit)

# grab some samples from the model
uSim <- data.frame(rvinecop(n=200,fit))
summary(uSim) # looks right but I want grams, mm, as the units
```

Comment: To convert the ranked data back to the original one, you can either transform one variable at a time using a quantile function (based on the marginal distribution), or you may try the `vinereg` package, which I think has a built-in function that can convert the data back to the original.